# Migrate to FastDateFOrmat instead of SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an app that was using SimpleDateFormat that we have since multithreaded and SimpleDateFormat is causing some issues.

I have read a bit about FastDateFormat but have never used it and would like to know how to do the following.

Currently I do something along the lines of :

```
String myDateString = "2015-08-10";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date myDate = sdf.parse(myDateString);
```

What is the equivalent to that using FastDateFormat?

I got as far as

```
FastDateFormat fdf = FastDateFormat.getInstance("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

But after that I dont see a clearcut way to get a Date instance returned.

Comment: `Date d = fdf.parse("2015-08-18")` http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29

Comment: fdf.parse is not available to me.  All i have is parseObject()

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/FastDateFormat.html

Comment: In version 2.6 (directly from document you provided): *"Parsing is not supported."*. Use a newer version.

Comment: If you're not in highly loaded production, I advice you just to create a new `SimpleDateFormat` for every request or keep them in `ThreadLocal` collection instead of using third-party libs.